# How to create const reference to pointer on const?

Tags: c++

I want to create the following class, but the compiler gives an error (it tells that the signatures of the methods are the same):

```
struct entities_set_less
{   
    constexpr bool operator()(const ContentEntity*& _Left, const ContentEntity*& _Right) const
    {   // apply operator< to operands
        return (_Left < _Right);
    }

    constexpr bool operator()( const const ContentEntity*& _Left, const const ContentEntity*&_Right) const
    {   // apply operator< to operands
        return (_Left < _Right);
    }
};
```

From my point of view, an expression like `const const ContentEntity*&` means "const reference to pointer on const ContentEntity". It should be different from `const ContentEntity*&`, which is just "const reference to pointer on non const type".

Comment: Maybe: `const ContentEntity* const& _Left`

Comment: `const ContentEntity*&` is a non-const reference to pointer to `const ContentEntity`.

Comment: `const const T*&` is not `const (const T*)&`, it is `(const const T)*&`; the `const` is duplicated so one of them is ignored.

Comment: Why do you (think you) want to pass a const reference? The actual reference is implicity constant, anyway, unless I've totally missed your point. `foo(int& a)` and `foo(int &const b)` are the same signature, I believe.

Comment: @AdrianMole no, `foo(int&a)` and `foo(int & const b)` are different code. P.s. I may be wrong. I will check it. I always use signature const int& instead

Comment: Nope: they are the same. From MSVC: *warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored*. From clang: *error : 'const' qualifier may not be applied to a reference*.

Comment: Note that `const int&` is a reference to a const int. But `int& const` would be an attempt at a const reference to a (non-const) int.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, you are right. But I am still don't understand. I will reread c++. It's too complicated

Comment: Even if you *could* declare two such functions, how would the compiler know which one to call/use?

Comment: All references are "const", in the sense that they cannot be rebound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clarify (or attempt to) what you actually want. You say you want a "const reference" … but references are (effectively) `const`, anyway (i.e., once a reference variable is bound to its target, it cannot subsequently be bound to a different target).

So, what you may have meant is that you want the arguments in the second overload to be references to constant *pointers* to constant objects; that is, neither the pointers nor the objects can be modified (in your first overload, the pointed-to *objects* cannot be modified but the referred-to *pointers* can be.

To make the pointers `const`, you need to add that keyword *immediately after* the pointer indicator (`*`). Like this:

```cpp
struct entities_set_less {
    constexpr bool operator()(const ContentEntity*& _left, const ContentEntity*& _light) const
    {   // references to non-const pointers to const objects
        return (_left < _light);
    }
    constexpr bool operator()(const ContentEntity* const& _left, const ContentEntity* const& _right) const
    {   // references to CONST pointers to const objects
        return (_left < _right);
    }
};
```

---

Note that I have also changed your `_Left` and `_Right` identifiers to `_left` and `_right`, because IDs starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved. From [this C++17 Draft Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 5.10 Identifiers       [lex.name]
>
> …
> <sup>(3.1)</sup>     — Each
> identifier that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an
> underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the
> implementation for any use.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a lot of confusion about what the `const` applies to can be removed by adopting the east-`const` convention:

> const reference to pointer on const ContentEntity

```
ContentEntity const* const&
```

> const reference to pointer on non const type

```
ContentEntity* const&
```

This way, you know that the `const` always refers to what's on its left.

Also, when in doubt, I usually check on [cdecl](https://cdecl.org) the type of the variables I'm declaring.

Comment: If the const refers to what's on its left then why do you not put a space on the right. Make the visual match the binding: `ContentEntity const *const &ref`. Not sure why you find this more confusing: `const ContentEntity *const &ref`.

Answer (score 1):

`const const` is never correct. The rule to remember is that `const` applies to whatever is on its left. The exception is when `const` is the leftmost token, in which case it applies to the right. So, when you want to add `const`, add it to the right side of whatever you want to be `const`.

> How to create const reference to pointer on const?

So, let's start with a reference to a pointer:

```
ContentEntity*&
```

We want it to be a reference to a const pointer. We place `const` to the right of `*`. Since it applies to left, this means that the referred pointer is const:

```
ContentEntity* const &
```

We want it to be a const pointer to const object of type `ContentEntity`. We place `const` to the right of `ContentEntity`. Since it applies to left, this means that the pointed `ContentEntity` is const:

```
ContentEntity const * const &
```

Alternatively, since `ContentEntity` is the first token, we can place its const to the left:

```
const ContentEntity * const &
```

---

All that said, it's quite rare to explicitly use a reference to const a pointer. It's more typical to pass a copy of the reference. References to const pointers do occur often when instantiating templates.

Comment: position of const plays role. You missed the case `const ContentEntity*` - it's pointer to const type. it's not equalent to `ContentEntity* const` which simply means const pointer

Comment: Hmm. Correct insofar as it goes. But it doesn't address the issue that a class can't have two functions that differ only in one taking non-const refs and the other taking const refs. Can't have both `bool foo(int& a, int& b)` and `bool foo(int& const a, int& const b)`.

Comment: @LmTinyToon Well, you didn't want a reference to non-const pointer, so I didn't feel the need to show that.

Comment: @AdrianMole You cannot have `int& const` at all because you aren't allowed to add cv-qualifiers to references. You can add cv-qualifiers to the referred type, and you can have both `bool foo(int& a, int& b)` and `bool foo(int const&  a, int const&  b)` overloads.